# TableView in NavigationBar and Tabbar Switch Between Tabs Gets Bad Access

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm building an app that combines tabbar and navigation bar. In one of tabs, I have a UIButton and by touching it, I push a Tableview into stack of navigationcontroller. Then, without returning to the root view controller manually by pressing Back buttons I change to another tab from tabbar and when I come back to the tab with the tableview inside, I get bad access error.

I've already tried popping the tableview from navigation controllers stack, or not releasing the tableview but I could't make it.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've created your tabBar and Navigation Controllers in the AppDelegate, you can code your app to return each tab to the root view when it is selected.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (viewController == firstViewNavigationController) {
        [firstViewNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    } else if (viewController == secondViewNavigationController) {
        [secondViewNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

I am using this and it is working fine in my app.  I am releasing my Navigation Controllers in the dealloc method.  I have also made my AppDelegate conform to the UITabBarDelegate protocol.